# Mongoose - How to cascade delete using pre hook remove

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a moment schema, which can have multiple comments associated to it. When a moment is deleted i want all the comments associated with the moment to also be deleted.

MomentSchema

```
let MomentSchema = new Schema({

    body: String,
    likes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    }],
    dislikes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    }],
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment',
    }],
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },

},
    {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'},
    });

MomentSchema.pre('remove', (next) => {

//What to include here to delete all the comments for this moment

});
```

FYI a comment can also have a reply which is also a comment model and therefore i would also need a pre remove hook in the comment model?

CommentSchema

```
let CommentSchema = new Schema({

    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    moment: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Moment',
    },
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',
        required: true,
    },
    likes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    }],
    dislikes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    }],
    parent: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Comment',
    },
    replies: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Comment',
    }],

},
    {
        timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at'},
    });
```

API DELETE: moment/:id

```
 destroy(req, res) {

        let id = req.params.id;

        Moment.findOne({'_id': id}, (err, moment) => {

            if (err) {

                return res.status(404).json({

                    success: false,
                    status: 404,
                    data: {},
                    message: 'Failed to find moment',

                });

            }

            moment.remove((err, moment) => {

                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        status: 400,
                        data: err,
                        message: 'Failed to delete moment',
                    });
                }

                return res.status(200).json({

                    success: true,
                    status: 200,
                    data: {},
                    message: 'Successfully deleted moment',

                });

            });


        });
```

}

What do i need to delete in the pre-hook to delete all the comments associated with the moment. In addition when calling "this" in the pre-hook remove it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to remove all comments && multi cascade i have to call the .remove method on the document. With the below code inserted into the moment pre-hook remove function it will delete the comments before removing the moment.

In addition before removing the comment it will call the comment pre-hook. Where i can add code to remove the replies to each comment.

```
 Comment.find({'moment': this._id})
        .then((comments) => {
            Promise.all(comments.forEach((comment) => comment.remove()))
                .then(next());
        });
```

A promise.all was used here as we only want to delete the moment once all comments have been deleted